# what is the reason to send an ack message by client before server window is over?

Tags: sockets, tcp

the  situation is this :

the client  starting  connection establishment 
and requesting a file .
the server  start to send the  file 
but  in the middle of  the server  sending window  the  client send an ack message .
is it because the  server  sending rate is higher ?
is there more  reason  or condition for that to happen?

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement to wait for the end of the window; quoting [RFC 2018](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2018.txt)

> The receiver SHOULD send an ACK for every valid segment that arrives
>      containing new data

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: This behaviour reduces latency.

Comment: can u give  me  a short answer  about the condition for that to happen ?

Comment: @user764812, suppose the receiver waited for the end of the sender's window before ACK'ing the first segment in that block; you now have a zero-window condition at the sender.  This means it must wait at least `0.5*RTT` for an ACK to arrive before it can send again.  If ACKs are sent continuously, the window can slide with the ACK'd data and data-flow has a greater chance of proceeding quickly.